# What does spoiler mean?

Tags: support

Sorry for being dumb here. But really before joining this site, I had no idea what the word `spoiler` means in case of movie discussion. After joining here, I have seen the word like `spoiler alert` here in several questions and answers. Also in IMDB, I found this keyword. Several other sites also use this keyword in different way.

**So what does the keyword `spoiler` mean in case of discussion on movie?**

Also here in faq, it is written `Please note that spoilers are allowed here and may be out in the open.` What does it mean either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A spoiler is a piece of information about a movie that reveals a rather important part of the movie, thus **spoiling** the surprise for someone who hasn't seen the movie yet.

Comment: Got it. Here in our college friends who have already seen a movie, rag others telling the story in front of them and the later section of friends get annoyed. It is a kind of prank. :D